# How to add a program (in this case gmsh) to the PATH

Tags: windows, command-line, path

I am looking to add a program into the `PATH` of my command line on my Windows computer. I have done this previously for Python. I thought it should be straightforward to do the same exact thing but with a different program called gmsh. Basically I am just editing the path in system settings from my control panel. So I add `;c:\gmsh285\gmsh285Windows\gmsh`. When I check to see if this works in terminal  gmsh is still not recognized.

Any pointers? Thanks ahead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is `gmsh.exe` a file within the directory `"c:\gmsh285\gmsh285Windows\gmsh"` or is `"c:\gmsh285\gmsh285Windows\gmsh"` the path to the executable itself?

You need to add the **executable's path** into the **path** variable, so if the executable is  `"c:\gmsh285\gmsh285Windows\gmsh.exe"` then you can *invoke* it as `"c:\gmsh285\gmsh285Windows\gmsh"` **or** `"c:\gmsh285\gmsh285Windows\gmsh.exe"`**or** {add `"c:\gmsh285\gmsh285Windows"` to the path and then invoke the executable using **either** `gmsh` **or** `gmsh.exe`}

That is, **path** is a semicolon-separated list of the **directories** to be scanned for the executable.

Comment: Thank you. Adding "c:\gmsh285\gmsh285Windows" to the path does it! I can now call gmsh from the command line.